# Getting Gitlab runner details for all runners

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to get to the contacted_at field for all runners on a gitlab instance and get the values inside Logstash.

gitlab.example.com/api/v4/runners/all gives an abbreviated list of all runners, but the details are hidden unless they are called by a specific ID. Is there a way to do this without specifying each and every runner's ID?

Comment: Currently no, not using the REST API. There may be a way to do so using the GraphQL API however (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/graphql/). Otherwise, you can [create an issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/new) with Gitlab. They review them regularly, and if you're a paying customer it will add more weight to your issue.

Answer (score 0):

[GitLab 14.8](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/02/22/gitlab-14-8-released/#view-read-only-runner-details-in-the-admin-area) (February 2022) comes with:

> ### View read-only runner details in the Admin Area
>
> You can now view the details of a runner in the Admin Area. This new view aims to provide the most valuable information about each runner associated with your GitLab instance. You can view last contact, runner version, and assigned projects, which is now paginated. In the new paginated jobs tab, you can also view a full list of jobs run by the Runner, which helps you view, search, and analyze CI/CD job execution history quickly.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/14_8/admin-runner-details-read-only-view-2.png -- View read-only runner details in the Admin Area]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/admin_area/#administering-runners) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/347856/).

This is not what you want, but the associated issue for that GUI feature, [issue 347856](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/347856/), includes multiple GraphQL API evolutions which could be of interest.

- "[Add createdAt to Runner GraphQL API](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/merge_requests/77561)"
- "[Add editAdminUrl to Runner GraphQL API](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/merge_requests/77748)"
- "[GraphQL: Add projects property to CiRunner type](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/merge_requests/78547)"

Maybe that means a GraphQL query is now possible to get much more information for *all* runners, since this is what the GUI is using to display that new list.

---

And: See [GitLab 15.0](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/05/22/gitlab-15-0-released/#view-more-details-about-each-runner) (May 2022)

> ### View more details about each runner
>
> Previously, if wanted an at-a-glance view of a runner’s relevant information, you had to switch between screens or even use the API to retrieve the details. Now, administrators can view the runner’s executor, architecture, and platform on the runner’s detail view. These details can help you quickly determine essential details, which are critical for troubleshooting issues or managing day-to-day operations and maintenance tasks.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/15_0/runners-detail-new-attributes-2.png -- View more details about each runner]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/admin_area/#administering-runners) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/352885).

---

[GitLab 16.4](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2023/09/22/gitlab-16-4-released/#users-with-the-maintainer-role-can-view-runner-details) (September 2023) adds:

> ### Users with the Maintainer role can view runner details
>
> Users with the Maintainer role for a group can now view details for group runners. Users with this role can view group runners to quickly determine which runners are available, or validate that automatically created runners were registered successfully to the group namespace.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/16_4/group-maintainers-view-runners.png -- Users with the Maintainer role can view runner details]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/permissions.html#group-members-permissions) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/384179).